monitor switching problem on lubuntu
i am using lubuntu and i have two monitors for my pc the main and another i have old graphic cards the setting of display keep changing i did try to write a script to it wont change but that didnt work tryed to install drivers normally from lubuntu but my graphic cards are so old plz help
s-pc:~$ lspci | grep -i vga
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Robson CE [Radeon HD 6370M/7370M] 

i cant find

You say you wrote a script, what does that script do?  Have you tried using the ubuntu-drivers tool on the command line to look for the proper drivers? (run sudo ubuntu-drivers list to see if specific driver pacakges are recommended.)  Also, what Lubuntu version are you using?

xrandr --output LVDS-1 --primary --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x0 --output VGA-1 --mode 1600x900 --pos 1366x0 
that is the script trying make the settings primary
using lubuntu 24.04 lts
@rufus-pc:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list [sudo] password for rufus:  udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.

Please add additional detail to your question; comments are intended to be from readers to OP, and will get removed once addressed in question. Its the question details that is answered (plus greater formatting is allowed in questions/answers)

I use arandr on Lubuntu, a screen layout editor. It's a GUI for Xrandr.It's in the repositories, might be worth a try.
